# StreamWriter disposed when accessing method

Tags: c#, .net, class

I'm facing a problem where my declared StreamWriter gets disposed when I try to use a method to write on my log file. Everything is working as expected, except when I run *AttachPink* or *AttachBlue*, from another class. Then the StreamWriter is disposed and I get a nullPointerException

```
class Logs : IDisposable
    {

        //other declarations

        private StreamWriter HistoryWriter;
        private int ReportInterval = 0;

        public void NewHistory()
        {
            HistoryWriter = new StreamWriter(HistoryLocation + HistoryName + HistoryExtension);
            PrepareHistory();
        }

        private void PrepareHistory()
        {
            HistoryWriter.WriteLine("<html><body bgcolor='#000000'>");
            /*
             *  Insert initial HTML tags 
             */
        }

        public void SendHistory()
        {
            HistoryWriter.WriteLine("</body></html>");
            /*
             *  Final HTML tags
             */ 
            HistoryWriter.Close();
            if (ReportInterval > 0)
            {
                /*
                 *  Upload File
                 */
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: Report Interval for History has not been set");
            }
            NewHistory();
        }

        public void AttachPink(String message, StreamWriter writer)
        {
            writer.Write(
                "<font color='DA1BE0'>" 
                + message
                + "</font>");
        }

        public void AttachBlue(String message, StreamWriter writer)
        {
            writer.Write(
                "<font color='0C93ED'>" 
                + message
                + "</font>");
        }

        public StreamWriter getHistoryWriter()
        {
            return HistoryWriter;
        }

        public void SetHistoryInterval(int interval)
        {
            ReportInterval = interval;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (HistoryWriter != null)
            {
                HistoryWriter.Close();
                HistoryWriter.Dispose();
                HistoryWriter = null;
            }
        }

    }
```

To use the methods I simply declare an instance of Logs class inside another class, like so:

```
class UsingLogs
    {
        Logs logs = new Logs();
        logs.NewHistory();
        logs.AttachBlue("my message", logs.getHistoryWriter());
    }
```

I don't know how should I go for preserving classes variables state when accessing multiple methods.

Comment: I did that on an attempt to solve the issue described, obviously didn't work though.

Comment: Then you should simplify your code back to something saner. Ideally, produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. I suspect there's some relevant code you haven't shown us yet.

Comment: I don't think the bug is in the code shown. Anyway, it does help you nothing if someone points you to the bug. I strongly recommend that you take this as an opportunity to learn hot to debug a program. Don't stare at the code till you see the problem. Set breakpoints and use F10.

Comment: It would seem likely that you're closing the streams in the calling code (maybe through a `using` clause?)? The code as shown, while unusual (and following atypical C# coding conventions), doesn't have any obvious way of causing the behavior you're showing. The syntax of the `class UsingLogs` isn't valid at all ... not sure where that is being used.

Comment: I used debug, and according to the 'Watch 4' the HistoryWriter is not null until I access the Attach* methods.

Also not using "using" I have even commented the dispose method, the issue still persisted.

Comment: @blacblu why is it suddenly null when you enter the method. Maybe you are looking at a different variable? Hover the mouse over different variables to see their value.

Comment: No, not looking at a different variable, it's the same that gets set when running NewHistory()

Comment: This seems to be some unhappy confabulation of two different approaches to this problem. Either you go down the singleton route, in wnich case no using clause, or you instantiate the writer each time in which case no HistoryWriter member. PS Have a look at Path.Combine, instead of that concatenation you are using.

Comment: Yes, I'm gonna go with singleton. And thank you for the Path.Combine tip, I'm gonna implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is the Singleton Pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

a simple implementation of mine which you can reuse every time you need a singleton

```
public class Singleton<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private static object sync = null;
    private static volatile T i;
    protected Singleton() { }

    public static T I
    {
        get
        {
            if (i == null)
                lock (sync)
                    if (i == null)
                        i = new T();

            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

You can implement your Log class like this:

```
class Logs : Singleton<Logs>
{
... your code goes here
}
```

In your code, when you want to use the Logs class, you simply use:

```
Logs.I.AttachBlue(...);
```

Hope this helps :)